# What rate does the code have?

Tags: information-theory

The block code $C\subseteq GF(2) ^6$ consists of all binary sequences of length 6 with hamming weight $w = 4$.
The rate of a block code is defined as the ratio between its message length and its block length:

$$R=k/n$$

How do I know what is k in my code? n=6

Comment: does the answer address your question?

Comment: Sorry but no. @kodlu

Comment: A nonlinear code does not have an integer dimension since the number of its codewords is not a power of the alphabet size. So if you wanted to compute a rate for an arbitrary code you use the formula I gave. If you wanted to be inexact, $k=\log_2 M$, but it is not an integer, nor a dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\binom{6}{4}=15$ codewords and a nonlinear code since sum of two codewords need not be a codeword. Thus the rate of your code is $$\log_2 15/6$$ but the dimension is undefined in the usual sense.

Linear codes, being vector subspaces, have well defined dimensions, which are integers.